# Wordpress Woocommerce - Change pay button url in my account

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to edit the URL for the **Pay button** in **My Account**.

The button currently sends the user to `/checkout/order-pay/28077/` I need this to remove the `/order-pay/` as this page doesn't show the various custom fields that I added to the normal purchase path.

I've looked through the template files but can't find the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's set in the `Checkout endpoints` section under the dashboard menu WooCommerce Settings/Checkout/Checkout Options.  Scroll down the page to the `Pay endpoint` and you'll see the default value of `order-pay`

Alternative is to use this filter if you want to remove it completely.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_actions', 'modify_woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_actions', 10, 2 );

function modify_woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_actions( $actions, $order ) {

    if( isset( $actions['pay']['url'] ) ) {
        $actions['pay']['url'] = str_ireplace( 'order-pay/', '', $actions['pay']['url'] );
    }

    return $actions;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Andrew. What I need is to remove the pay endpoint so that the customer is sent to checkout without the /order-pay/

Changing the field suggested only renames order-pay endpoint.

Comment: I've updated my answer to show how you can use a filter to remove it.

Comment: Thanks, Andrew. I've added your code and all is working nicely. Much appreciated.